# c# jamaa: smpp esm_class byte value

Tags: c#, .net, smpp

all.

I am using c# jamaa smpp libraries v1.4.
And when I am getting the delivery_sm from SMSC - it tries to parse the incoming message. I have an issue here.
The incoming byte value for esm_class is 4, as you can see on screenshot:
[image: Incoming deliver_sm message bytes]
But the EsmClass in Jamaa has the next values

```
public enum EsmClass : byte
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default SMSC mode, default message type, or no specific features selected
    /// </summary>
    Default = 0x00,
    /// <summary>
    /// Datagram mode
    /// </summary>
    DatagramMode = 0x01,
    /// <summary>
    /// Forward (i.e. Transaction) mode
    /// </summary>
    Transaction = 0x02, //Forward mode
    /// <summary>
    /// Store and forward mode
    /// </summary>
    StoreAndForward = 0x03,
    /// <summary>
    /// Short message contains SMSC delivery receipt
    /// </summary>
    DeliveryReceipt = 0x08,
    /// <summary>
    /// SME contains ESME delivery acknoledgement
    /// </summary>
    DeliveryAcknoledgement = 0x08,
    /// <summary>
    /// SME contains ESME manual/user acknoledgement
    /// </summary>
    ManualUserAcknoledgement = 0x10,
    /// <summary>
    /// Short message contains conversion abort (Korean CDMA)
    /// </summary>
    ConversionAbort = 0x18,
    /// <summary>
    /// Short message contains intermedicate delivery notification
    /// </summary>
    IntermediateDeliveryNotification = 0x20,
    /// <summary>
    /// UDHI Indicator (only relevant for MT network)
    /// </summary>
    UdhiIndicator = 0x40,
    /// <summary>
    /// Set Reply path (only relevant for GSM network)
    /// </summary>
    ReplyPath = 0x80
}
```

As you can see - it awaits the 8 value, to return DeliveryReceipt.
What is going wrong? Is it enough just to correct the EsmClass code - to return DeliveryReceipt when the 4 value is coming?

Thank you.
With regards, Yuriy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like esm_class is defined incorrectly. For a delivery receipt in deliver_sm it should be set to 4. If it's an MO it would be set to 0. You correcting this to 4 is perfectly fine and you should not encounter any issues. Refer to the SMPP protocol specification if you need more info.

Comment: Hi, Kim.
Thank you again :-)

With regards, Yuriy.

Answer (score 0):

ok. I just modified the library EsmClass code to
"
DeliveryReceipt=0x04; 
"
And it works. For 2 days I was testing and didn't meet any problems.